# Image interpolation - nearest neighbor (Processing)

Tags: java, image-processing, processing

I've been having trouble with an image interpolation method in Processing. This is the code I've come up with and I'm aware that it will throw an out of bounds exception since the outer loop goes further than the original image but how can I fix that?

```
PImage nearestneighbor (PImage o, float sf)
{
  PImage out = createImage((int)(sf*o.width),(int)(sf*o.height),RGB);
  o.loadPixels();
  out.loadPixels();
  for (int i = 0; i < sf*o.height; i++)
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < sf*o.width; j++)
    {
      int y = round((o.width*i)/sf);
      int x = round(j / sf);
      out.pixels[(int)((sf*o.width*i)+j)] = o.pixels[(y+x)];
    } 
  }

  out.updatePixels();
  return out;
}
```

My idea was to divide both components that represent the point in the scaled image by the scale factor and round it in order to obtain the nearest neighbor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For getting rid of the `IndexOutOfBoundsException` try caching the result of `(int)(sf*o.width)` and `(int)(sf*o.height)`.

Additionally you might want to make sure that `x` and `y` don't leave the bounds, e.g. by using `Math.min(...)` and `Math.max(...)`.

Finally, it should be `int y = round((i / sf) * o.width;` since you want to get the pixel in the original scale and then muliply with the original width. Example: Assume a 100x100 image and a scaling factor of 1.2. The scaled height would be 120 and thus the highest value for `i` would be 119. Now, `round((119 * 100) / 1.2)` yields `round(9916.66) = 9917`. On the other hand `round(119 / 1.2) * 100` yields `round(99.16) * 100 = 9900` - you have a 17 pixel difference here.

Btw, the variable name `y` might be misleading here, since its not the y coordinate but the index of the pixel at the coordinates (0,y), i.e. the first pixel at height y.

Thus your code might look like this:

```
int scaledWidth = (int)(sf*o.width);
int scaledHeight = (int)(sf*o.height);
PImage out = createImage(scaledWidth, scaledHeight, RGB);
o.loadPixels();
out.loadPixels();
for (int i = 0; i < scaledHeight; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < scaledWidth; j++) {
    int y = Math.min( round(i / sf), o.height ) * o.width;
    int x = Math.min( round(j / sf), o.width );
    out.pixels[(int)((scaledWidth * i) + j)] = o.pixels[(y + x)];
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm still getting an out of bounds exception in the right side of the assignment ( o.pixels[(y+x)] ) =/

Comment: @TarekMerachli could you give an example of the initial dimension, the scale factor, the scaled dimension and the y and x values that result in the exception?

Comment: Initial dimensions are 800x600, scale is 2 and I checked the scaled dimensions and they were correct (1600.0 x 1200.0). When I try to print the x and y values the program just crashes :P Really hate Processing for not having a debugger.  Also, the out of bounds is occurring at index 480,000

Comment: @TarekMerachli I forgot to include the `Math.min(...)` in my code but mentioned it in the text. Here the problem is the following: the highest value for `i` can be 1199 and thus `1199/2 = 599.5` which will be rounded up thus resulting in `600` which is just out of range (the original height range is 0-599). I'll add the min check to my answer's code.

Comment: Ah yes you're right :P I changed it to o.width-1 and o.height-1 instead because o.width was also giving me an out of bounds. Thanks a ton :)

Comment: @TarekMerachli oops, you're right :) yes, o.height would be 600 but the maximum y allowed would be 599. \*blushed cheeks\*